# How to sort a list by multiple attributes and units?

Tags: sorting

I'm trying to find a source of information to explain how to sort a list of items considering their multiple attributes and units. All I can find on the internet is code example on sorting Javascript lists and SQL queries.

The key is that it must compare Price, Probability and Color at the same time, for example. A higher price not necessarily should be the first element of the sorted list. If Probability is too high or if the color is Red, it should be priorized.

I understand that I must transform the values to be sorted to the same unit.

Anyone has a clue how do this?

Comment: This is more of a question for the stackoverflow main site, doesn't really fit here. You didn't say what language are you using. There's usually some kind of sort or orderBy method that takes a comparison function that determines the relative ordering of two items - you can do the kind of test you need there. See for example how the comparison function (the one passed as the `compareFunction` parameter to sort) is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (scroll down a bit).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8760570/1493294) what you’re looking for?

Comment: To add to answers and comments - what I suggested is a "piecewise function" (if a then x if b then y else z) that determines the relative ordering of any two items (less then, equal, greater then); the alternative is to come up with some kind of metric that gives an absolute ordering for any given item, based on some calculation that combines all the inputs and outputs a single number - think of it as being a position on a line.

Answer (score 2):

### Ordering is always one-dimensional and linear

> A higher price not necessarily should be the first element of the sorted list. If Probability is too high or if the color is Red, it should be priorized.

Whenever you order a list, you use some linear comparable value (e.g. price) for each element in order to decide the order of the elements (e.g. ranging from the highest price to the lowest price).

Your ordering, no matter what criteria you order by, will always boil down to a single linear comparable value.

In your case, there is apparently a lot of complicated logic to it. You didn't specify the exact rules, but for the sake of example, I'm going to use the example criteria of [expected value](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/expected-value/), i.e. `expectedPrice = price * probability` (e.g. a game with a $20 prize and a 25% of winning the game will statistically win you $5 on average).

You can calculate the expected price, returning a single linear comparable value for each element. Since you didn't specify a language, I'm using C#:

```
public int GetExpectedPrice(MyObject o)
{
    return o.Price * o.Probability;
}

// Examples

var expectedPrice_1 = GetExpectedPrice(new MyObject() { Price = 20, Probability = 0.25 }); // = 5
var expectedPrice_2 = GetExpectedPrice(new MyObject() { Price = 50, Probability = 100 }); // = 50
var expectedPrice_3 = GetExpectedPrice(new MyObject() { Price = 8, Probability = 0.125 }); // = 1
```

Of course, you should create a method which mirrors your own logic. This is just an example.

Once you've established a way to map an object to its ordering value (in this case the expected price), ordering the list becomes a trivial task:

```
var myObjects = ...; // get a list of objects

var myOrderedObjects = myObjects.OrderBy(o => GetExpectedPrice(o));
```

And that's all there is to it.

The only tricky part is deciding the criteria for your ordering, but we cannot decide this for you. Your business rules are contextual and not universally applicable/known.